# WxWidgets || Creating makefile

Tags: makefile, wxwidgets

I'm trying to compile my program using makefile.

My code:

```
zad2_1Main: zad2_1Main.o zad2_1App.o
    g++ -o zad2_1Main zad2_1Main.o zad2_1App.o wx-config.exe --cxxflags

zad2_1Main.o: zad2_1Main.cpp
    g++ -c zad2_1Main.cpp wx-config.exe wx-config.exe --cxxflags

zad2_1App.o: zad2_1App.cpp
    g++ -c zad2_1App.cpp wx-config.exe wx-config.exe --cxxflags
```

But i have error:

```
unrecognized command line option '--cxxflags'
```

wx-config.exe is in the same folder as the files

My files:

```
Zad2_1App.cpp
Zad2_1App.h
Zad2_1Main.cpp
Zad2_1Main.h
```

Comment: Well, you've added the flag `--cxxflags` to the compile line, but that is not a valid compiler option... _exactly_ as the error message says.  So you should take that out.  I don't know what it's supposed to be there for.

Comment: It's a valid compiler option, please check first before answer.

Comment: It's clearly _NOT_ a valid option, because the compiler is telling you it's not recognized.  Why do you think it is a valid option?  Here's a hint: check the documentation for your compiler to find the valid options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the *output* of `wx-config` to the compiler, not the literal string itself. Moreover, it's pretty wasteful to run the shell script again and again for each and every source file. So instead you should do the following:

```
WX_CXXFLAGS := $(shell wx-config --cxxflags)
WX_LIBS := $(shell wx-config --libs)

zad2_1Main: zad2_1Main.o zad2_1App.o
    g++ -o zad2_1Main zad2_1Main.o zad2_1App.o $(WX_LIBS)

zad2_1Main.o: zad2_1Main.cpp
    g++ -c zad2_1Main.cpp $(WX_CXXFLAGS)

zad2_1App.o: zad2_1App.cpp
    g++ -c zad2_1App.cpp $(WX_CXXFLAGS)
```

Your makefile could be improved in several other ways, but this should at least work.

Answer (score 0):

@Tacoo.

You should use backticks around `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs`.

Something like

```
g++ -o zad2_1Main zad2_1Main.o zad2_1App.o `wx-config.exe --cxxflags`
```

Comment: One executes, but the other fails with wx-config.exe - not found. Why? If the first one loads this file correctly, why doesn't the second one?

Comment: @Tacoo, Which OS are on? You should drop the `.exe` postfix. This is just an OS script.